# Find the lowest value n such that $\frac {n^2-38}{n+1} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the lowest value n such that $\frac {n^2-38}{n+1}$ is an integer

So, it's not really hard to notice that n can't be an integer different to 0, and 0 could be the lowest value, but maybe there's a non-integer n that satisfies such equation.I've tried to factorize, and acomplish $$\frac {(n-6)(n+6)-2}{n+1} $$
But i still find nothing. 
So i'm looking for a hint or answer,thanks

Comment: ... such that *what*?

Comment: i'm missing some words, such that $$\frac{n^2-28}{n+1}$$...?

Comment: so that that thing is an integer?

Comment: I'm assuming this means such that $n+1$ divides $n^2-38$

Comment: "it's not really hard to notice that n can't be an integer different to 0": please show us

Comment: Sorry i missed it, it should be an integer

Comment: And i said that by parity, like, if n is an even number then n^2 - 38 is too, and n+ 1 should be odd but i actually missed that an odd number can divide and even, sorry again

Comment: if you let $n$ be any real then there is an infinite number of solutions, the function $n-1+\frac{37}{n+1}$ contains  all positive reals in its image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n^2-38=(n+1)(n-1)-37$

Therefore $\frac{n^2-38}{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)(n-1)-37}{n+1}=n-1+\frac{37}{n+1}$.

Hence the division is an integer if and only if $n+1$ divides $37$, since $37$ is prime the only values are $-38,-2,0$ and $36$.

Comment: what part of mexico? have you tried out the OMM?

Comment: Yucatán. I've been in ONMAPS (Olimpiada nacional de matematicas para alumnos de primaria y secundaria) but this year i'm in OMM

Comment: Cool, maybe I'll see you in Monterrey then.

Comment: Who knows, i'm still in a pre-selection, that's why i'm practicing a lot